# ReportServer from 2008R2/2012/2014 to ReportServer 2016

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Recently I have been experiencing a lot of issues with taking ReportServer database from older instances of SQL Server to SQL Server 2016.
I simply take a backup of the database and restore it on an sql server 2016, restart the service and then try to access the ReportManager URL, that will give me an error, I then check the SQL logs and here's the error:

" library!WindowsService_0!7c40!07/10/2017-16:59:39:: e ERROR: ServiceStartThread: Exception caught while starting service. Error: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot convert to text/ntext or collate to '결鉱á.慏⨠翺...' because these legacy LOB types do not support the Unicode supplementary characters whose codepoints are U+10000 or greater. Use types varchar(max), nvarchar(max), or a collation which does not have the _SC flag. "

Both instances are named MSSQLSERVER, they're all installed by default except I use a domain account to manage the different SQL services.

That's what I can think of at the moment, I will answer to all questions and such I really want to get this fixed without the need to upgrade the whole sql instance.

Thank you,

Comment: Read this, there are many steps involved with a migration.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/migrate-a-reporting-services-installation-native-mode

Answer (score 0):

Has to do with moving both database and following the instructions on that link:
"https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8eebf25f-2c40-40d3-9bb7-bb481fdafc12/is-this-a-scaleout-deployment-?forum=sqlreportingservices"